# has_many through => find not matching records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I want to be able to find unpopulated hives, but don't find any solution.
Can you help me please ?
The goal is to be able to do Hive.unpopulated
The main problem is the most_recent, butins ok for me to work with a raw  SQL, but I don't find the right query.

Here are my classes :

```
class Hive < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :moves, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :yards, through: :moves
  has_many :populations, -> { where(:most_recent => true) }
  has_many :colonies, through: :populations 
  
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  
  def hive_with_colony 
    "#{name} (colony #{if self.colonies.count > 0 then self.colonies.last.id end})"
  end
  
  def self.populated
    Hive.joins(:populations)
  end
  def self.unpopulated
    
  end
  
end
```

```
class Population < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hive
  belongs_to :colony
  
  after_create :mark_most_recent
  before_create :mark_end
```

```
class Colony < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :populations, -> { where(:most_recent => true) }
  has_many :hives, through: :populations
  has_many :visits
  has_many :varroas
  
  has_many :most_recents_populations, -> { where(:most_recent => true) }, :class_name => 'Population'
  scope :last_population_completed, -> { joins(:populations).where('populations.most_recent=?', true)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do a simple query to select Hives which are not in populated list, so:

```
def self.unpopulated
  where.not(id: populated.select(:id))
end
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I know with Rails there was an easy way to do it !

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and picking the lines that have no population id set on the right side.

```
def self.unpopulated
  left_outer_joins(:populations).where(populations: { id: nil })
end
```

It depends on your data if Thanh's version (which compares a potentially huge list of ids) or this version (which makes a sightly more complex join but doesn't need to compare against a list of ids) is more performant.